# Unable to restart my network services

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I cannot restart my networking services by using the `restart` command. Earlier it was working fine but today I created a lot of mess by giving IPs removing and all.

And now when I enter the `restart` command, it shows that the network is stopping, restarting & soon after it shows some errors and got stuck. Below is the restart command which I entered;

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Please help me on this.

**P.S:** Also tell me; if I assign an IP using `vi /etc/network/interfaces`; then do I have to use below line before assigning IP or DHCP;

```
auto eth0
```

Comment: May I ask for the output of `ifconfig` & `cat /etc/network/interfaces` please. You may [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/419379/edit) your question and update it. Also please specify what's the exact error you're receiving.

Comment: if you use the network manager you can't (or shouldn't) do settings with the /etc/network/interfaces file...
if you have to edit this file you need the "auto eth0" before you tell if you want dhcp or static! The auto ethx starts the interface then your system boots. the iface eth0 static ... tells your system that u'll use a static ip and the iface eth0 dhcp tells it to use a dhcp server. for more help you have to paste your /etc/network/interfaces file...